# HTTP Error 500.19 from Membership Provider on IIS 8.0 mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-membership, iis-8

I am trying to provide custom membership on my asp.net MVC application. But I am getting an error message from web server; pointing something wrong with Web.config file. Here is my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AmarTaka24ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AmarTaka24;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings> 

<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
<providers>
<add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="AmarTaka24.net.MyMembershipProvider, AmarTaka24.net, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"/>  
</providers>
</membership>
```

It's pointing an error on `<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">` . 
Additional Information: This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
Is there any problem with this code? how can I solve this issue?
( VS13,sql server,windows 10)

Comment: You left out the most important thing... what is the error message...?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the event logs like the message says?

Comment: Error Message: Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid. @Zack